# No getter method for property - JSP Exception

Tags: java, jsp, struts, javabeans

In my `Struts-config.xml` file,

```
<action path="/getTareWeight" 
  type="com.astrazeneca.usbod.scale.actions.GetTareByBarcodeAction"  
  name ="getTareByBarcodeForm" 
  scope="request" 
  validate="true" 
  input="/jsp/getTareByBarcode.jsp">

    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/tareWeightResult.jsp" />
  </action>
```

In `GetTareByBarcodeForm` which extends the `ActionForm` the following getter and setter methods are there,

```
public String getBarcodeString() {
    return (this.barcodeString);
}

public void setBarcodeString(String barcodeString) {
    this.barcodeString = barcodeString;
}

public String getResult() {
    return (this.result);
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

In the `GetTareByBarcodeAction.java` file,

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException{
      String target = new String("success");
      double tareWeight=0;
      String tw = new String("");
      GetTareByBarcodeForm gForm = (GetTareByBarcodeForm)form;
      String errorString;
      StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(gForm.getBarcodeString(),
      " \t\n\r\f:,;.");
      List barcodeList = new ArrayList();
      List tareWeightList = new ArrayList();
      while (t.hasMoreTokens()) {             
        barcodeList.add(t.nextToken().trim());           
      }
      int size = barcodeList.size();
      VesselProcessor vproc = VesselProcessor.getInstance();
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        tareWeight = vproc.checkTares((String) barcodeList.get(i));
        tw=Double.toString(tareWeight);
        tareWeightList.add(barcodeList.get(i));
        tareWeightList.add(tw);
        String temp = barcodeList.get(i).toString();
        gForm.setBarcodeString(temp);
        gForm.setResult(tw);
      }

    request.setAttribute("TAREWEIGHT", tareWeightList);
    return (mapping.findForward(target));       
}
```

In the `tareWeightResult.jsp` file, i am printing the values in the attribute TAREWEIGHT in a table format.

```
<logic:present name="TAREWEIGHT">
        <logic:iterate id="result" name="TAREWEIGHT">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <bean:write name="result" property="barcodeString"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <bean:write name="result" property="result"/>
                </td>
            </tr>           
        </logic:iterate>
    </logic:present>
```

When I tried to run this functionality after deploying it in weblogic server, I have the below error in log.

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property barcodeString of bean result
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(RequestUtils.java:968)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag.doStartTag(WriteTag.java:286)
at jsp_servlet._jsp.__tareweightresult._jsp__tag2(__tareweightresult.java:237)
at jsp_servlet._jsp.__tareweightresult._jspService(__tareweightresult.java:174)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
```

Can anybody let me know where I have gone wrong in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from your code, there are no `GetTareByBarcodeForm` instances in the `tareWeightList`: the latter contains `String`s, so when `bean:write` tries to extract the property, it cannot: `String` doesn't have such a getter.

Perhaps you should revisit your logic extracting the values, and wrap the results in proper instances.

So your code should look more like the following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tareWeight = vproc.checkTares((String) barcodeList.get(i));
        tw = Double.toString(tareWeight);
        String temp = barcodeList.get(i).toString();

        GetTareByBarcodeForm f = new GetTareByBarcodeForm();
        f.setBarcodeString(temp);
        f.setResult(tw);
        tareWeightList.add(f);
    }
```

so that the result list, the one you pass as `TAREWEIGHT`, would contain proper objects.

Still, that's not too good: now, `GetTareByBarcodeForm` plays two roles, the actual form and the search result entry. So I would highly recommend introducing a new class, `TareTableEntry`, and only include table details in it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tareWeight = vproc.checkTares((String) barcodeList.get(i));

        TareTableEntry entry = new TareTableEntry();
        entry.setBarcodeString(barcodeList.get(i));
        entry.setResult(tareWeight);
        tareWeightList.add(entry);
    }
```

That's more code, but it pays off in a long run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Could you pls give me an outline of the logic which should be applied? The requirement is like user will enter a set of barcodes and click submit button. Each barcode is associated with a weight in DB. I want to display these barcodes along with their weights in the table format in the jsp page.

Comment: Whoa, that's way too many requirements for a single question :) Editing the answer to give you an idea, hold on for a sec.

Comment: BTW.. Sorry for disturbing ;)

Comment: If the user enters six different barcodes, then the tareWeightResult.jsp page prints the sixth barcode and its corresponding tareweight value six times in the table format. How to resolve this? Please help

Comment: Log `barcodeList` just before the cycle; create a `toString()` method in `TareTableEntry` or `GetTareByBarcodeForm`, and log `tareWeightList` just after the cycle. It should give you an idea on the place where things got wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6314/discussion-between-lgap-and-alf)

Answer (score 0):

The id with "result" is represented by TAREWEIGHT. Does this object has the barCodeString property ? It looks to me that there is some problem with the bean name in

```
<bean:write>.
```